# Reset array to initial state (delete all elements)

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays

I was wondering which was the appropriate way to reset an array to initial state, and so delete all the elements that it contains.

I found the following ways:

1. `delete paidPlayers;`
2. `paidPlayers.length = 0`
3. `array = new type[](0)`

I understand that those are equivalent from a result point of view, however I suppose there are differences about gas usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity docs recommends using `delete array`

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.23/miscellaneous.html#tips-and-tricks

> Use delete on arrays to delete all its elements.